# How much load can a VPS server with these specs handle?

Tags: mysql, centos

Processor Info:
[image]

Memory:
[image]

OS: Cent OS

I have a third party API I will be using, that will be feeding millions of possible queries every 30 seconds - 1 minute to my VPS. The datasets to be sent will be small, as in, the numbers '88' and '95' for example. Or '100', '75', and 'by John Jones'

Can my VPS handle this?

Comment: Millions of API requests every 30 seconds? At one million, that's ~33.3k API requests per second. I don't care how well you optimize your code, there's no possible way you can do this with a single VPS. As an aside, scaling questions are for all intents and purposes unanswerable without vast amounts of data and testing, which only you can perform.

Comment: It sounds quite unlikely.  but you haven't told us anything about what is done with the data?  is it thrown away?  do you add 1 to the number and return it?  write it to disk?  Do millions of calculations before returning a result?  Depending these answers there would be wildly different requirements.

Comment: millions of API requests every minute on a cpanel box... good luck

Comment: Once the data is fed to the system, the system just outputs the value... doesnt do any calculation or anything.

Comment: Would this be better suited on using an AWS service like Amazon EC2 or something?

Comment: @JohnDeer - for this load, you're going to need multiple servers *somewhere* behind a load balancer, and perhaps multiple load balancers. Where those servers live is up to you. EC2, while very nice to use, is not magic. You still need to have expertise on developing and supporting scalable, distributed applications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To Answer your question NO is probably the answer you will find, not at anywhere near the number your thinking of.

if the memory screen shot is correct you only have 100MB of ram (i suspect its cut off) EDIT it shows 1GB ram

The screenshot looks awfully like its from the cpanel interface which is more than definitely not tailored and optimized for your possible use case so performance would be far less than optimal

as the comments suggest, how many requests you can receive and process depends totally on what your doing with them. but with hardware that spec i doubt its even possible for the box to even receive that number of requests in the time frame you want

companies that do API processing on that level tend to have multiple (large) servers dedicated to the task of processing that data and be load balanced between them for HA also

nothing beats doing proper research and testing, why not test a smaller amount of queries and monitor performance, test and different levels and graph average performance metrics and you should be able to work out what you actually need or what the box is actually capable of